# GRUB loader configuration

Tags: 12.04, grub2, 12.10, kubuntu, configuration

Today I removed the Win7 partition that came with my laptop and installed Kubuntu 12.10 (along with my default OS Ubuntu 12.04).

Later, I discover that the GRUB configuration that manage my boot is the one from Kubuntu, however, I'd like to be the configuration from Ubuntu 12.04.

**Is it possible that the GRUB from Ubuntu overtakes the one from Kubuntu?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing Kubuntu 12.10 after Ubuntu 12.04 you probably overlooked the option to disable the installation of the bootloader. It's enabled by default and will overwrite your current (Ubuntu 12.04) bootloader.

Luckily, you can just reinstall Grub from within your desired OS and thereby overwriting the one currently in place on the MBR of your hard drive. So, boot into your Ubuntu 12.04 OS (that's still possible, I guess, right?) and read the [community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2) on this topic on how to reinstall Grub. Your Ubuntu 12.04 installation should just detect your other OSs fine.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm!!! I tried before with `update-grub` :-P but nothing happened. Thanks again.